# Disable storyboard auto layout connection safe area default

Tags: autolayout, storyboard

How do I stop the safe area being the default connection? I want the connection to be between the subview and the superview.

[image: Connection]

[image]

Comment: If you click the "down arrow" in the size field (to the right of `54`) you can select `View` instead of `Safe Area`. The default is to constrain to the safe area because, well, ***NOT*** doing so is an exception.

Comment: An exception? Really? Selecting the down arrow suggests that the default is the safe area and I have to accept that?

Comment: I could probably word that better... what I meant was: The *default* is the safe area because that is - in general - where we want to set our constraints. So, for the instances where we want to constrain to the superview instead, that would be considered "non-default" or an "exception." I'm not saying one **should not** constrain to the superview... there are plenty of valid reasons to do so... but I assume Apple makes the safe area the default since that is what is most often used.